# How do I write a link in HTML/PHP that makes the user download a file?

Tags: php, html, file, download

I am writing a program in PHP that uses file uploading and file downloading.  The one problem is that the files can be any type, and I don't know how to make it so that the link makes a download popup appear.  How do I do this?

Thanks!

Nerd With a Vengeance

Answer (score 2):

So to help put this all together for you.

Page 1 (User selects a file to download)

files_to_download.php (file that user sees)

```
<a href="download.php?file=file1.pdf">PDF File</a>
<a href="download.php?file=file1.doc">Word Doc File</a>
<a href="download.php?file=file1.ppt">Power Point File</a>
```

download.php (file that is linked to)

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];

// set your path
$path = '/path/to/your/files/';

// you'd probably want to do some error check here
// e.g. does file exist, etc.

// start download
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="blah.dat');
```

into the PHP file that serves the download, the browser will always open a download window, even for files it could handle by itself.

Comment: So, where would I put this?  I have a loop printing out links to the files.  Should the header be included in this loop?

Comment: You can't do that from the page with the link, you have to do it in the page that is downloaded.

Comment: See my answer for a solution if the download files are static.

Comment: So, you mean that I have to put in a page for each downloadable file?

Comment: No, one page for all of them. It can accept a parameter to choose which file to download.

Comment: Make sure you do not introduce security holes thoug (like allowing users to pass *any* file/path to download). Setting the header via .htaccess is probably safer.

Comment: I'm confused. So, what I have is a MySQL database that has the names of all the files. The location of each file is always files/filename.extension and the PHP script loops through this database and prints out links that look like <a href = "files/$filename"> which prints regular links.  Where am I supposed to put these header tags so that the links become download links?

Comment: You need to create a file for example called download.php. There you put those headers in. You change the links to download.php?file=filename.extension. The download.php file checks if it is allowed to download that file (important!) by checking the directory and type and then echoes out the file.

Comment: So does the PHP of download.php look like this?   $dl = $_GET['dl'];
 header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$dl');

Answer (score 0):

Setting the appropriate content disposition should work:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
```

You need to do this in the PHP script which sends the file contents. If the files are static and not served via PHP you can also do it using a .htaccess file (when using Apache):

```
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
```